# Android - Activity uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: android, realm

I have literally created a brand new Android Project on the latest Android Studio. The first thing I did was to add the `Realm' library to the project by adding the following to the gradle file:

```
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.80.3'
```

If I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
Note: C:\....\MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
```

> Origin 2:
>   C:\Users\Usmaan.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.realm\realm-android\0.80.3\7979d05ba7b919c53766bf98e31aaf0e9feb0590\realm-android-0.80.3.jar Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK
>   C:...\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk  Path in archive:
>   META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor   Origin 1:
>   C:\Users\Usmaan.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.jakewharton\butterknife\6.1.0\63735f48b82bcd24cdd33821342428252eb1ca5a\butterknife-6.1.0.jar
>   You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:  android {
>   packagingOptions {
>         exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'     } Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
>
> > Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor   File 1:
> >     C:\Users\Usmaan.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.jakewharton\butterknife\6.1.0\63735f48b82bcd24cdd33821342428252eb1ca5a\butterknife-6.1.0.jar
> >       File 2:
> >     C:\Users\Usmaan.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.realm\realm-android\0.80.3\7979d05ba7b919c53766bf98e31aaf0e9feb0590\realm-android-0.80.3.jar    }

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like you are also using Butterknife? Have you tried adding the below to your build.gradle:

```
android {
  ...

  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
  }
}
```

Comment: where to add this?

Comment: In module-level gradle (app/build.gradle), inside android {}, for example next to lintOptions or defaultConfig

Answer (score 15):

Adding this to the `android` plugin in build.gradle tends to fix these sorts of problems:

```
    packagingOptions {
        // Exclude file to avoid
        // Error: Duplicate files during packaging of APK
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'
    }
}
```

Comment: Also I use:  exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")

Answer (score 5):

Adding these on build.gradle as Specified in [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) I/O page.

```
android{
....
packagingOptions {
  exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
}


}

lintOptions {
  disable 'InvalidPackage'
}
```